# Read Textfile into Safearray

Tags: c++, file-io, safearray

I need to read a textfile and store the data into a Safearray.

I tried it with this function:

```
bool Parse::LoadTxtFileIntoSafearray(string* strPath, SAFEARRAY** pByteArray)
{
bool bReturn = false;

string line;
int iOffset = 0;
char* pcBuffer = NULL;

std::ifstream infile ( strPath->data() );
if ( !infile.fail() )
{
    infile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int iSize = infile.tellg();
    infile.seekg(0);
    pcBuffer = (char*)calloc(iSize,sizeof(char));
    if(pcBuffer)
    {
        infile.read(pcBuffer, iSize);
        iSize = strlen(pcBuffer);
        SAFEARRAYBOUND sb;
        sb.cElements = iSize;
        sb.lLbound = 0;
        *pByteArray = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1,1,&sb);

        BYTE* pData;
        SafeArrayAccessData(*pByteArray,(void **)&pData);
        memcpy(pData, pcBuffer,iSize);
        SafeArrayUnaccessData(*pByteArray);
        delete pcBuffer;
        pcBuffer = NULL;
        bReturn = true;
    }
}
return bReturn;
}
```

The Problem is that the size of the file is bigger than the read bytes...

What is wrong?

regards
camelord

Comment: off topic but why are you using `delete` with `calloc`?

Comment: no reason.. could also create a local buffer.. i change it.

Comment: is use SAFEARRAY because i need an Array to pass it through ComServer Interfaces.. but that is not the question.

Comment: @Neil: One of those COM abominations ;) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221482.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [man-page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read), read attempts to read upto *count* bytes.  To be sure you read all bytes, you have to loop.

As a side-note: you're not always guaranteed to work with a static file, so assuming that the files-size won't change could get you in trouble (buffer-overrun, not reading the complete file, endless loop).